# Overlaying scatterplots with varying amount of data

Tags: r, plot

I'm trying to plot three different data sets on the same plot. I have 32 datapoints for the first set, 38 for the second set, and 48 for the third set.

I can't bind them together in a data.frame in order to pass them into `matplot` and I'm not sure what to do.

Any thoughts / methods to do this (it's probably something easy that I've just never seen before)?

They are all completely independent of each other, and there's no reason why I shouldn't be able to over lay them.

Comment: Did you try `points`? e.g. `plot(1:10); points(1:5, rep(2, 5), col=2); points(1:5, rep(4, 5), col=3)`

Comment: @sgibb That will add some points, but I'm not certain how I should define the plot window in order to encompass all of the points I'll be adding without adding any additional points to the plot

Comment: Use `xlim` and `ylim` to define the window size: `plot(1:10, xlim=c(0,20), ylim=c(0,15))`

Comment: Yeah, but I don't want to have points like 1:10 on the plot. I guess I can find the limits of all of my points, and plot one data set in the max range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

e.g.

```
d1 <- data.frame(x=runif(20),y=runif(20))
d2 <- data.frame(x=rnorm(10),y=rnorm(10))
d3 <- data.frame(x=rpois(5,5),y=rpois(5,5))
allD <- rbind(d1,d2,d3)
plot(y~x,data=d1,xlim=range(allD$x),ylim=range(allD$y))
with(d2,points(x,y,col=2))
with(d3,points(x,y,col=4))
```

or:

```
plot(y~x,data=d1,xlim=range(allD$x),ylim=range(allD$y),type="n")
mapply(function(x,c) with(x,points(x,y,col=c)),
       list(d1,d2,d3),c(1,2,4))
```

or:

```
allD$group <- rep(1:3,c(20,10,5))
plot(y~x,data=allD,col=allD$group)
```

or:

```
library(lattice)
xyplot(y~x,groups=group,data=allD)
```

or:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(allD,aes(x,y,colour=factor(group)))+geom_point()
```

Comment: This ignores the original issues of the problem... I have datasets with varying amounts of points. All three of your data sets have 10 points

Comment: yes, but the recipe should work fine in any case.  I'll modify accordingly.